# Sql help to find username in a data set

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Data

```
     row  data
      1  (172.32.313.20:5892) User 'ant\john' requested 
      2  User ant\john logged on from 172.31.13.2129
      3  user=ant\john domain=ant.amazon.com server=172.31.19.541 protocol=LDAPS result=0:Success
```

I need to pull the username (john) from this dataset .

```
select message,replace(TRIM(split_part(split_part(message, 'requested', 1), 'User ', 2)), 'ant\\', '') username1,
replace(TRIM(split_part(split_part(message, 'requested', 1), 'user=', 2)), 'ant\\', '')username2
from test_kemp_log.archive
where message like '%john%'
```

Is there a better way to extract User(user)  ant/  information from dataset?

Comment: Have you tried regular expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following could work in your case.

```
SELECT regexp_substr(data, 'ant\\\\'||'([a-z]+)', 1,1, 'e'), data From test_kemp_log.archive
WHERE message like '%john%';
```

'e' is for extracting the first group. In our case, it's the first thing that matches `([a-z]+)` after "ant\".